# i.vi writing null data to output raster on first attempt

Tags: grass-gis, shell, bash

I have the following lines of code in a bash script I wrote using osgeo's GRASS command line tools:

```
i.vi viname=ndvi output=$ndvi_fn nir=$nir_fn red=$red_fn --overwrite
while r.info $ndvi_fn -r | grep NULL;do
  echo "Failed to write NDVI file, trying again"
  sleep 2
  i.vi viname=ndvi output=$ndvi_fn nir=$nir_fn red=$red_fn --overwrite
done
```

This will loop indefinitely. If I stop my script, and rerun it, usually the NDVI band is actually written to the file. Sometimes the third try or more (not always on the second attempt). I can not understand for the life of me why restarting the script makes a difference from sleeping and running it again.

The script will only work if I comment out the while loop, and I rerun the script. I have also tried using `g.remove type=raster name=$ndvi_fn -f` in the while loop to remove and recreate the file every iteration. no luck.

Has anyone else seen erratic behavior with `i.vi`? I checked [the docs](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass80/manuals/i.vi.html).. but it seems like I'm using it correctly.

Comment: Silly question, has the computational region been set to the input map(s)? `g.region raster=$nir_fn [-p]`. Just to be sure...

Comment: actually no.. I was doing it AFTER I created the NDVI image. i'll move it before and try again! Thanks for something to try!

Comment: it worked! Seems obvious in hindsight. Thank you so much @markusN !! If you'd like, please paste your comment as an answer so I can accept the answer. Thanks again, cheers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please be sure if the [computational region](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Computational_region) been set to the input map(s) prior to the `i.vi` command.
In your case, just use the variable to pass on the raster map name:

`g.region raster=$nir_fn [-p]`